# How to configure tags at time of creating a AWS RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, amazon-rds, scp

I am trying to create a AWS SCP to enforce some tags at time of resource creation.This is working fine for EC2,LAMBDA But for AWS RDS resource creation is failing as I am not able to give tags at time of creating

Created SCP and tried to create RDS instance through cli was able to give tags and create instance.But not getting option in management console

This is SCP

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyEC2CreationInfraOwnerTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances",
        "ec2:StartInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/InfraOwner": "true"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyEC2CreationProductTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances",
        "ec2:StartInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/Product": "true"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyEC2CreationNameTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances",
        "ec2:StartInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/Name": "true"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyLambdaCreationInfraOwnerTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "lambda:Create*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/InfraOwner": "true"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyLambdaCreationProductTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "lambda:Create*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/Product": "true"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyLambdaCreationNameTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "lambda:Create*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/Name": "true"
        }
      }
    },
        {
        "Sid": "DenyRDSCreationInfraOwnerTag",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "rds:CreateDBInstance",
            "rds:CreateDBCluster"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "Null": {
                "aws:RequestTag/InfraOwner": "true"
            }
        }
    },
        {
        "Sid": "DenyRDSCreationProductTag",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "rds:CreateDBInstance",
            "rds:CreateDBCluster"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "Null": {
                "aws:RequestTag/Product": "true"
            }
        }
    },
        {
        "Sid": "DenyRDSCreationNameTag",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "rds:CreateDBInstance",
            "rds:CreateDBCluster"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "Null": {
                "aws:RequestTag/Name": "true"
            }
        }
    },
        {
        "Sid": "DenyDynamoDBCreationInfraOwnerTag",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:CreateTable"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "Null": {
                "aws:RequestTag/InfraOwner": "true"
            }
        }
    },
        {
        "Sid": "DenyDynamoDBCreationProductTag",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:CreateTable"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "Null": {
                "aws:RequestTag/Product": "true"
            }
        }
    },
        {
        "Sid": "DenyDynamoDBCreationNameTag",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:CreateTable"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "Null": {
                "aws:RequestTag/Name": "true"
            }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Show us the SCP

Comment: Pasted in question

Comment: It doesn't look possible to supply tags at creation time in RDS via the console, which is really disappointing on AWS's part.